# Do "sword-swallowers" swallow swords?

Tags: weapons, stage-magic

Sword-swallowers, such as [Dan Meyer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Aw7EkIsYK0) claim to be putting a real metal sword down their throats.

Are they really pushing a piece of metal down their throats, or are they some sort of magic trick with fake swords?

Comment: **Note**: this question was asked as part of the "[topic of the week](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/topic-of-the-week-weapons)" initiative to raise our questions per day stat. Please contribute some great questions!

Comment: "Sword-swallowers" doesn't need to be hyphenated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sword swallowers are indeed placing a real metal sword down their throats and into their stomachs. It is (obviously) extremely dangerous and risky, which is part of what makes it so captivating to see.

[This site](http://www.swordswallow.com) which is affiliated with [Sword Swallowing International](http://www.swordswallow.org/about.php) has some good information and photos.

Quoting from their [FAQ](http://www.swordswallow.com/faq.php#gimmick):

> Q:  "Don't you use a gimmick, a fake sword that curls or folds up?"
>   "Don't you swallow a sheath first, or use a plastic tip on your
>   sword?"
>
> A:   No. Many people think that sword swallowers use a fake sword
>   (known as a "gaff" in the business) that curls or folds up into the
>   handle, but this is simply not the case for real sword swallowers.

[Photos](http://www.swordswallow.com/xrays.php) from the same site shows an X-ray of a swallowed sword:

This [clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5D9qcFBFmlk&feature=player_embedded) from Discovery Health shows Dan Meyer swallowing a sword and being X-rayed.

HowStuffWorks also has a nice [article](http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/circus-arts/sword-swallowing.htm) explaining that it is real and how it works:

> There is a trick to real sword swallowing, but it doesn't involve
>   illusions or preemptively-swallowed metal tubes. Instead, it involves
>   lots of physical and psychological preparation. For some performers,
>   learning to swallow a sword can take years. In this article, we'll
>   examine what it takes to swallow a sword and why sword swallowing is
>   an extremely dangerous practice.

There is also a 2006 study from the British Medical Journal which acknowledges that sword swallowers swallow real metal swords and looks at the side effects:

> Sword swallowers know their occupation is dangerous. The Sword
>   Swallowers' Association International (SSAI, www.swordswallow.org)
>   recognises those who can swallow a non-retractable, solid steel blade
>   at least two centimetres wide and 38 centimetres long. As we found
>   only two English language case reports of injury resulting from sword
>   swallowing,1 2 we explored the technique and side effects of this
>   unusual practice.
>   - [Source](http://www.bmj.com/content/333/7582/1285.full?ijkey=ME07xoblLL2bTXV&keytype=ref)

So yes, sword swallowers swallow real swords.

Comment: "As we found only two English language case reports of injury resulting from sword swallowing" - there's a challenge! Surely there's more.

Comment: +1, but please add a reference back to the source of the image, so we can see it isn't a copyright violation.

Comment: @Oddthinking image reference added.

Comment: +1 though, I think one of the xray images would be more useful than that cartoon

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I didn't add an x-ray image because it seemed that you had to apply for special permission to use them.

Comment: @Sonny: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The images have a disclaimer asking for permission if the images are to be used. I wish to respect that.

Comment: Alas, so did the cartoon source. Removed.

Comment: @Oddthinking so it did. I wonder why they decided to hide it as tiny text at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @BlueRaja: IANAL, but I do not consider such a usage - where we are not critiquing the photo itself - as fair-use. This is a topic for meta though, not here.

Comment: beautiful answer!

Comment: It would be interesting to know how sharp those swords are.

Comment: @Oddthinking, Witcombe & Meyer's BMJ paper notes near the end that two cases were already reported in English medical literature, but describes several others mostly minor. I've added an answer with a link to the paper.

Comment: Note: This is for some definitions of "sword". They do not have sharp edges, and I think in almost all cases are exclusivity designed to be swallowed. They are metal, and in a recognisably sword shape, but not designed to be used as a sword nor would they make good swords.

Still a dull sword is a sword.

Answer (score 6):

Quite real. Brian Witcombe and Dan Meyer are authors of a BMJ paper "[Sword swallowing and its side effects](http://www.bmj.com/content/333/7582/1285.full)" where they asked 110 sword swallowers about medical conditions related to sword swallowing of whom 46 responded.

Sore throats seem to be a common problem, but more serious problems such as intestinal bleeding are in there too.

> Thirteen respondents did not volunteer any medical information, but 19
>   described sore throats, usually when they were learning to swallow,
>   after performing too frequently, or when they were swallowing multiple
>   or odd shaped swords. Lower chest pain, often lasting days, followed
>   some performances and was usually treated by abstaining from practice.
>   They rarely sought medical advice. Six suffered perforation of the
>   pharynx or oesophagus. Three of these had surgery to the neck, one
>   having a 1.5 cm laceration at the level of D2 and a pneumothorax, one
>   a pinhole laceration at C6 and surgical emphysema, and the other
>   having a pharyngeal tear. The perforations were treated conservatively
>   in three patients, one of whom had a second perforation with
>   aspiration of a neck abscess after further injury. Three others also
>   had probable perforations, one of whom was told that a sword had
>   “brushed” the heart, and one had pleurisy and another pericarditis
>   after injury, suggesting extraoesophageal trauma. No one underwent
>   thoracotomy, although one had a breadknife removed transabdominally.
>   Sixteen mentioned intestinal bleeding, varying in quantity from
>   melaena or finding some blood on a withdrawn sword to large
>   haematemases necessitating transfusion. No members of the association
>   had died from sword swallowing, but the cost of medical care was a
>   concern with three members receiving medical bills around
>   $23 000-$70 000 (£12 000-£37 000, €18 000-€55 000).